Quanto pricing question, stuck on self financing strategy derivation

I'm a bit stuck on doing part 2, I'm not sure if I have done part 1 correctly...
\begin{align}
&\max \left( 0, X(T) \tilde{S}(T) - X(\theta) \tilde{S}(\theta) \right) \\
&\tilde{S}(T) = \tilde{S}(t) \exp\left[\left(\tilde{r} - \frac{1}{2} \xi^2 \right)(T-t) + \xi (\tilde{W}(T) - \tilde{W}(t))\right] \\
&X(T) = X(t) \exp\left[\left(r - \tilde{r} - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right)(T-t) + \sigma (W(T) - W(t))\right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{E}_\beta \left[e^{-r(T-t)} \left(X(T) \tilde{S}(T) - X(\theta) \tilde{S}(\theta)\right) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_\beta \left[ X(T) \tilde{S}(T) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] - e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_\beta \left[X(\theta) \tilde{S}(\theta) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathbb{P} Q X \tilde{S}}{\mathbb{P} Q_\beta} = \frac{\beta(t) X(T) \tilde{S}(T)}{\beta(T) X(t) \tilde{S}(t)} = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(\xi + \sigma)^2(T-t) + (\xi + \sigma)(W(T) - W(t)) \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{E}_\beta \left[e^{-r(T-t)} \left(X(T) \tilde{S}(T) - X(\theta) \tilde{S}(\theta)\right) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_\beta \left[X(T) \tilde{S}(T) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] - e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_\beta \left[X(\theta) \tilde{S}(\theta) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_\beta \left[X(T) \tilde{S}(T) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_Q \left[X(T) \tilde{S}(T) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \frac{\beta(T) X(t) \tilde{S}(t)}{\beta(t) X(T) \tilde{S}(T)} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
&= X(t) \tilde{S}(t) \mathbb{E}_Q \left[\mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
&= X(t) \tilde{S}(t) \mathbb{P}_Q \left[\{X(T) > X(\theta)\} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_\beta \left[X(\theta) \tilde{S}(\theta) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
&\tilde{S}(T) \text{ under the domestic measure:} \\
&\tilde{S}(T) = \tilde{S}(t) \exp \left[\left(\tilde{r} - \frac{1}{2} \xi^2 + \xi \sigma\right)(T-t) + \xi \left(W(T) - W(t)\right)\right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathbb{P} Q \tilde{S} \beta(t)}{\mathbb{P} Q_\beta} = \frac{\tilde{S}(T) \beta(T)}{\tilde{S}(t) \beta(T)} = \exp \left[\left(\tilde{r} - \frac{1}{2} \xi^2 + \xi \sigma\right)(T-t) + \xi \left(W(T) - W(t)\right) - r(T-t)\right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&= \exp \left[\left( \tilde{r} - r + \xi \sigma \right)(T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \xi^2 (T-t) + \xi (\tilde{W}(T) - \tilde{W}(t)) \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathbb{P} \tilde{Q} \tilde{S}}{\mathbb{P} Q_\beta} = \frac{\tilde{S}(T) \beta(t)}{\tilde{S}(t) \beta(T)} \exp \left[- (\tilde{r} - r + \xi \sigma)(T-t)\right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_\beta \left[X(\theta) \tilde{S}(\theta) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] &= e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_Q \left[ X(\theta) \tilde{S}(\theta) \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \frac{\tilde{S}(t) \beta(T)}{\tilde{S}(T) \beta(t)} \exp\left[-(\tilde{r} - r + \xi \sigma)(T-t)\right] \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&= X(t) \tilde{S}(t) \exp\left[- (\tilde{r} - r + \xi \sigma)(T-t) \right] \mathbb{E}_Q \left[ \mathbb{I}_{\{X(T) > X(\theta)\}} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
&= X(t) \tilde{S}(t) \exp\left[- (\tilde{r} - r + \xi \sigma)(T-t) \right] \mathbb{P}_Q \left[ X(T) > X(\theta) \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
C &= X(t) \tilde{S}(t) \mathbb{P}_Q \left\{ X(T) > X(\theta) \right\} - X(\theta) \tilde{S}(\theta) \exp\left[-(\tilde{r} - r + \xi \sigma)(T-t)\right] \mathbb{P}_Q \left\{ X(T) > X(\theta) \right\}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
d \tilde{W} &= dW - (\xi + \sigma) dt
\end{align}
\begin{align}
X(T) &= X(t) \exp \left[\left( r - \tilde{r} - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 + \sigma (\xi + \sigma)\right)(T-t) + \sigma (W(T) - W(t)) \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}_Q \left\{ X(T) > X(\theta) \right\} &= \mathcal{N} \left[ \frac{\log\left(\frac{X(t)}{X(\theta)}\right) + (r - \tilde{r} - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 + \sigma (\xi + \sigma))(T-t)}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 (T-t)}} \right] \\
&= \mathcal{N} \left[ \frac{\log\left(\frac{X(t)}{X(\theta)}\right) + (r - \tilde{r} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 + \sigma \xi)(T-t)}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 (T-t)}} \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
X(T) &= X(t) \exp \left( r - \tilde{r} - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 + \sigma \xi \right)(T-t) + \sigma(W(T) - W(t))
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}_Q \left\{ X(T) > X(\theta) \right\} &= \mathcal{N} \left( \frac{\log \left( \frac{X(t)}{X(\theta)} \right) + (r - \tilde{r} - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 + \sigma \xi) (T - t)}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 (T - t)}} \right)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
C &= X(t) \tilde{S}(t) \mathcal{N}(h_1) - X(\theta) \tilde{S}(t) \exp \left( - (\tilde{r} - r + \xi \sigma) (T - t) \right) \mathcal{N}(h_2)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
h_{1,2} &= \frac{\log \left( \frac{X(t)}{X(\theta)} \right) + (r - \tilde{r} \pm \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 + \sigma \xi) (T - t)}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 (T - t)}}
\end{align}
